# could not instantiate mail function

Tags: php, iis-7, phpmailer

Tearing my hair out on this one.

I have an internal Win2008 server running IIS7.0 and PHP 5.2.4. The email server is on a seperate server on the same network.

I can use php's mail function to send emails with no issues but when I use PHPMailerLite, I get the message "could not instantiate mail function".

I have researched a lot and tried the following but still no joy.

1. SetFrom - changed this to an existing email address on the mail server.
2. Verified SMTP settings in php.ini
3. Tested php's mail function directly and emails send no problem.
4. Downloaded PHPMailer again in case of corruption.

Any help would be appreciated.....

Alan

Just to add, the default examples included with PHPMailer doesn't work either, same error.
This code is working on other test servers for me.

```
$mail             = new PHPMailerLite();
$mail->IsMail(); // telling the class to use PHP Mail to send email
$mail->SetFrom("CareSys@localdomain.ie","CareSys");
$mail->AddReplyTo("CareSys@localdomain.ie","CareSys");
$mail->Subject    = "Weekly Planner";
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddAddress($email_add, $carer_name);
$mail->AddAttachment('../../temp/carer_planner.pdf','carer_planner.pdf');      // attachment
$mail->ConfirmReadingTo = 'info@localdomain.ie';
if(!$mail->Send()) { $error_count=1; }

if ($error_count<1) { echo 'Email Sent Successfully'; }
```

If I put the recipient address directly in the class file on line 582 instead of the $to vairable, it works. But using $mail->AddAddress($email_add, $carer_name) will not even if I replace the $email_add variable with the receipient address.

Comment: ¿Could you paste here some of the code using PHPMailerLite?

Comment: Yes Sorry. Just to add I cannot get the default included examples to work either, same error.

Comment: There's about four lines between line 576-596 that are: $rt = @mail($val, $this->EncodeHeader($this->SecureHeader($this->Subject)), $body, $header, $params); can you remove the @ from before the mail, run the program and report back with the new error.

Comment: Didn't know that debug option was available. The error now is a 504 error, invalid address. This error normally indicates the address in the initial HELO but I have entered this on line 152 as the value for $hostname and still the same error.

Comment: Sorry should have added that the error now is referencing line 582 in class.phpmailer-lite

Comment: If I put the recipient address directly in the class file on line 582 instead of the $to vairable, it works. But using $mail->AddAddress($email_add, $carer_name) will not even if I replace the $email_add variable with the receipient address.

Comment: Problem solved and it was thanks to Ben for informing me of the additional debug option.

The issue was with the second part of $mail->AddAddress('info@recipient.ie', 'John Doe');.

When I removed the name, the email sends fine - $mail->AddAddress('info@recipient.ie');

Comment: move your comment to answer and mark it as right answer

Comment: There's no option to flag a comment as an answer.

Comment: No, but there is copy+paste functionality.

Answer (score 0):

That class is trying to send the message via the "sendmail" program, which is not using the php mail function. Be sure that you can execute programs from PHP via the exec/system functions, and that you can run sendmail program from PHP. The exec/system/passthru/popen functions may be disabled by your server administrator, or your php environment may be jailed and can not access the sendmail program at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **SMTP** to send email:-

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.example.com";    

// optional
// used only when SMTP requires authentication  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'smtp_username';
$mail->Password = 'smtp_password';
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$mail->SetFrom("CareSys@localdomain.ie","CareSys", 0); //notice the third parameter
```